# fixing dbtimestamp conversion mistake

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am using ssis to convert a dd-mm-yyyy varchar input into a dbtimestamp field, using the data conversion transformation. My mistake was that the conversion produces a yyyy-mm-dd where mm is the dd from the input and the dd is the mm. So if i have an input 04-01-2019 00:00:000 it produces 2019-04-01 00:00:000.

my solution is to use substrings to transform the input into standard iso format YYYY-MM_dd first and then convert to datetime data type. My problem is how am i going to correct the existing records (move dd to mm and mm to dd)? Probably substrings again?

Comment: I'm surprised the data got inserted. if you have a value like `'13-01-2018'` that would have generated a conversion error (there aren't 13 months in a year). Considering the high likelihood that at least one of your dates would have been for the 13th of the month or more, are you sure that the data got inserted? In the event of a failure ideally your ETL process should be set up to rollback the transaction(s), or create a clean slate when it starts again. If it did contain such dates, however, then how is that data appearing in SQL Server if the insert succeeded.

Comment: If you already have the data on SQL Server, updating the values there will be much easier.

Comment: i am redirecting the conversion errors to a text file allowing it to carry on with the transactions. I can confirm it inserts the dates while they 're not irrational like the example you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table only has incorrectly implicitly cast values (like `'04-01-2019'` (`dd-MM-yyyy`) to `20190401`) and none which haven't been, you could use `CONVERT` and some style codes:

```
SELECT D,
       CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),V.D,101),103)
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'20190401'))) V(D);
```

As an `UPDATE` statement, that would be:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourDateColumn = CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),YourDateColumn ,101),103);
```

This converts the `date` back into a `varchar` with the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, and converts it back to a date but treats the value as `dd/MM/yyyy` (thus switching the day and month).